# ASP.NET Setting HtmlInputRadioButton name in GridView from code behind

Tags: asp.net

On the `RowDataBound` event of a gridview I am setting the name of the `HtmlInputRadioButton` inside the `GridViewRow`. The problem is that asp.net automatically makes the name unique therefore ungrouping the radio buttons.

Is there a way that I disable this?

Edit -
Here's how I am setting the name:

```
  Private Sub gvFoo_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSecPos.RowDataBound
If Not (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) OrElse (e.Row.Cells(0) Is Nothing) Then
  Return
End If
Dim drFoo As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

Dim rbFoo As HtmlInputRadioButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("rbFoo"), HtmlInputRadioButton)
rbFoo.Name = "Foo" 'ASP.NET makes this unique which I do not want
rbFoo.Value = "A Value"

  End Sub
```

Produces this html

```
<input type="radio" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucFoo_gvFoo_ctl06_rbFoo" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucFoo$gvFoo$ctl06$Foo" value="A Value">

<input type="radio" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucFoo_gvFoo_ctl07_rbFoo" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucFoo$gvFoo$ctl07$Foo" value="A Value">
```

Instead of

```
<input type="radio" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucFoo_gvFoo_ctl06_rbFoo" name="Foo" value="A Value">

<input type="radio" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucFoo_gvFoo_ctl07_rbFoo" name="Foo" value="A Value">
```

Due to the numbers "106" and "107" in the name of the respective radiobuttons it ungroups them.

Comment: When you say "name" do you mean the server side control ID or the client side input name?

Comment: How does it make it unique? What does it churn out?

Answer (score 5):

You can override the name of the radio button by overriding the getter of the UniqueID

```
    private class MyHtmlInputRadioButton : HtmlInputRadioButton
    {
        public override string UniqueID
        {
            get
            {
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? base.UniqueID : Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't this marked as the answer? Simple, elegant and it works. Thank you @igor-z

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the plain radio button instead. `<input type="radio" name="blahblah"/>`

Comment: I need to set the name from code behind since I am setting it to the value of a variable

Comment: If you are binding some collection or list to the gridview the just set one property in the corresponding class and `<input type="radio" name='<%# Eval("MyRadioButtonName")%>'/>`

Comment: The variable isn't from the datasource it is from somewhere else

Comment: If there is any way that you can get the variable in some function.`<input type="radio" name='<%# MyFunction() %>'/>` and write the function `public string MyFunction()`

Comment: What I've done is generate the html in a literal control. But wanted to know if there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     HtmlInputRadioButton control;
    if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        control = e.FindControl("ControlID") as HtmlInputRadioButton;

    }
    control.name ="xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue attempting to define a radio group using either a RadioButton or HtmlInputRadioButton within a Repeater control.  The RadioButtonList would not work in my case, because the HTML needed to be rendered in a way that the RadioButtonList was not capable of (I was applying Twitter Bootstrap to an existing ASP.NET WebForms site).

My workaround used JavaScript w/jQuery to remove the UniqueID information, that is tacked on to the name attribute of the radio buttons, then reapply the original name attribute when the form is submitted.  The original name must be restored, otherwise an error will occur upon PostBack when ASP.NET attempts to restore the state of those controls.

This workaround worked fine in my scenario, but beware of any possible side-effects or edge cases.  The page that I applied this to was fairly simple.  I did not verify if it works with client-side validation.

Here is an example of the JavaScript code that I used:

```
$(function(){

    $('input.custom-radio-name').each(function(i, radio){
        var name = radio.name,
            groupNameIndex = radio.name.lastIndexOf('$') + 1,
            groupName = radio.name.substring(groupNameIndex);
        // Preserve the original name, so that it can be restored
        $(this).data('aspnetname', name); 
        radio.name = groupName;
    });

    $('form').submit(function(){
        // Restore the name of the radio buttons,
        // otherwise errors will ensue upon PostBack.
        $('input.custom-radio-name').each(function(i, control){
            var aspnetname = $(this).data('aspnetname');
            control.name = aspnetname;
        });
    });

});
```

See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/yumN8/